# SQL Select query for report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Table A:
Name     intID  
name a |   0
name b |   1
name c |   2
name d |   3

Table B:
Occurrences      intID
day1          |    0
day2          |    0
day3          |    1
day4          |    0
day5          |    0
day6          |    0
day7          |    3
day8          |    0
```

First table describes the names, the second tracks occurrences.
I am trying to build a report that needs to select from a drop down menu only the names that have occurrences. I can already do that, however I can't get the drop down menu to include the name from table A.
Right now I do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 'Item #' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), intID) + ' ' + (SELECT ???? )
FROM TABLE B
GROUP BY intID ORDER BY intID
```

The SELECT statement marked with ???? is where I am stuck. I need to add the name of the appropriate name from table A there.

I hope that is clear, as I am a beginner in SQL :)

Thanks for any help in advance !

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MSSQL 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join table A and table B on `intID`. Then you can query `a.Name` as shown.

```
SELECT 'Item #' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), b.intID) + ' ' + a.Name
FROM b
INNER JOIN a ON b.intID = a.intID
```

---

Example:

```
;WITH a AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('name a',0),
                 ('name b',1),
                 ('name c',2),
                 ('name d',3)) x(name, intID))
, b AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('day1',0),
                 ('day2',0),
                 ('day3',1),
                 ('day4',0),
                 ('day5',0),
                 ('day6',0),
                 ('day7',3),
                 ('day8',0)) y(Occurrences, intID))

SELECT 'Item #' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), b.intID) + ' ' + a.name as result
FROM b
INNER JOIN a ON b.intID = a.intID
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! It worked, as I am able to pull this and get the data, however I can't figure out how to group it properly. When I do SELECT as name, intID
, then GROUP BY intID 
I do get an ambiguity error.
Any ideas ? 
Thanks !

Comment: The ambiguity involves not knowing which `intID` you are selecting. Prefix it with the table alias, for example `a.intID`

Comment: Sorry, should’ve said I already tried that, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, when I used only 1 parameter to ORDER by it was giving me a different error, I had to use both parameters for a.name and b.intID in order for this to work with ORDER / GROUP

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to query from two tables.

```
SELECT a.something,b.something FROM a JOIN b USING(intID);
```